# retrofit2 upload works in Emulator but not on real Device

Tags: php, android, ssl-certificate, retrofit2

I use retrofit to upload a previously recorded Video, but every time I try to upload it from my phone it fails where as on the emulator it works just fine. I do get the error from my php file on the server though so there's some kind of connection. I suspect it has to do with a certificate?
Here are my classes:

MainActivity

```
package com.inducesmile.androidvideorecording;


import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 300;
    private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri uri;
    private String pathToStoredVideo;
    private VideoView displayRecordedVideo;
    private static final String SERVER_PATH = "http://78.108.216.189";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayRecordedVideo = findViewById(R.id.video_display);
        Button captureVideoButton = findViewById(R.id.capture_video);
        captureVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent videoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if(videoCaptureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    startActivityForResult(videoCaptureIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE){
            uri = data.getData();
            if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                displayRecordedVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
                displayRecordedVideo.start();

                pathToStoredVideo = getRealPathFromURIPath(uri, MainActivity.this);
                Log.d(TAG, "Recorded Video Path " + pathToStoredVideo);
                //Store the video to your server
                uploadVideoToServer(pathToStoredVideo);

            }else{
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.read_file), READ_REQUEST_CODE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
    }
    private String getFileDestinationPath(){
        String generatedFilename = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String filePathEnvironment = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        File directoryFolder = new File(filePathEnvironment + "/video/");
        if(!directoryFolder.exists()){
            directoryFolder.mkdir();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Full path " + filePathEnvironment + "/video/" + generatedFilename + ".mp4");
        return filePathEnvironment + "/video/" + generatedFilename + ".mp4";
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, MainActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
        if(uri != null){
            if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                displayRecordedVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
                displayRecordedVideo.start();

                pathToStoredVideo = getRealPathFromURIPath(uri, MainActivity.this);
                Log.d(TAG, "Recorded Video Path " + pathToStoredVideo);
                //Store the video to your server
                uploadVideoToServer(pathToStoredVideo);

            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User has denied requested permission");
    }

    private void uploadVideoToServer(String pathToVideoFile){
        File videoFile = new File(pathToVideoFile);
        RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
        MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SERVER_PATH)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        VideoInterface vInterface = retrofit.create(VideoInterface.class);
        Call<ResultObject>  serverCom = vInterface.uploadVideoToServer(vFile);
        serverCom.enqueue(new Callback<ResultObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResultObject> call, Response<ResultObject> response) {
                ResultObject result = response.body();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result.getSuccess())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result " + result.getSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result " + result.getSuccess());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResultObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error message " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    private String getRealPathFromURIPath(Uri contentURI, Activity activity) {
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }
    }
}
```

ResultObject

```
package com.inducesmile.androidvideorecording;

public class ResultObject {
    private String success;
    public ResultObject(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

VideoInterface

```
package com.inducesmile.androidvideorecording;


import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;
public interface VideoInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/imagefolder/index.php")
    Call<ResultObject> uploadVideoToServer(@Part MultipartBody.Part video);
}
```

Here's my php

```
<?php

$result = array("success" => $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
$file_path = basename( $_FILES['video']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    $result = array("success" => "Erfolgreich hochgeladen");
} else{
    $result = array("success" => "Fehler");
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

Thank you in advance